# How can I make a control know if one of its children receives focus?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, focus

In Silverlight, controls can contain other controls.

I want to make my control know if any control further down the visual tree has received focus.

Is there a standard pattern for this and, if not, how could I do it?

UPDATE: I've found that the GotFocus event is bubbled up so a top level grid will see GotFocus fire each time a control within it or, crucially for me, within its children gets focus.

So now I'm wondering if this is always the case?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the event GotFocus is exactly what you need.